# boost::chrono readable duration

Tags: c++, boost

I have been working on a profiler that times functions in microseconds using boost chrono and it works well for small functions but I tend to get very high number with bigger ones.

Imagine the following scenario

```
boost::chrono::duration<long long, boost::micro> us1(300);
boost::chrono::duration<long long, boost::micro> us2(200000);

std::cout << boost::chrono::duration_short << "us1: " << us1 << ", us2: " << us2;
```

The output will look like this

> > us1: 300 us , us2: 200000 us

which can become hard to quantify so i'd like to know if there is a way to round to the higher unit so that the output can look like

> > us1: 300 us , us2: 200 ms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to everyone, I solved it that way:

```
const std::string readableDuration(const boost::chrono::duration<long long, boost::micro>& duration)
{
    std::stringstream stream;
    int digits = calcNumDigits(duration.count());

    stream << boost::chrono::duration_short;

    if (digits <= 3) {
        stream << duration;
    } else if ((digits > 3) && (digits <= 6)) {
        stream << boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::milliseconds>(duration);
    } else if ((digits > 6) && (digits <= 9)) {
        stream << boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::seconds>(duration);
    } else if (digits > 9)
    {
        stream << boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::minutes>(duration);
    }

    return stream.str();
}
```

Might be worth making stream static but you get the general idea